# Parsing a log file by applying condition

Tags: python, regex, bash, shell, text-processing

I have a debug log file as you can see below:

Sample file:

```
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output
output output
output"
DEBUG: extra lines
```

I want to fetch only the IDs and the final output as shown below.

Expected output:

```
<ID> "output
output output
output"
```

I would like to do this in either python or bash. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Current code works for "final output" only. but I want to fetch IDs as well and there should be a way to distinguish (seperator) for each ID and their output.

```
stream=open("debuglog.txt","r")
lines=stream.readlines()

flag = 0
for i in lines:
    if "DEBUG:" in i:
        flag = 0
    if "final output is" in i:
        flag = 1
    if flag:
        print(i)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Please explore `re` module in python. It will come in handy for such pattern matching

Comment: I've edited the question and added my code. The problem with it is that either it fetches ID or output only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python, how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
text = open("logfile", "r").read()

regex = r'start (.+?)$.*?Final output is (.+?)(?:(?=\nDEBUG)|\Z)'
for m in re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    for i in m.groups():
            print(i.replace('\n', ' '))
```

Input logfile:

```
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output
output output
output"
DEBUG: extra lines

DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID2>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output2
output+ output/
output2"
```

And the output:

```
<ID>
"output output output output"
<ID2>
"output2 output+ output/ output2"
```

- The 1st parens in regex captures any characters just after `start` and before the newline and stores the string into the `1st group`.
- The 2nd parens in regex also captures any characters just after `Final output is` and before `DEBUG` or the end of the string and stores the string to the `2nd group`. Newlines can be included in the string due to `re.DOTALL` option.
- The 3rd parens are null-length anchor and is not included in the capture group.

**EDIT**

The updated version below handles multiple "final output" for a single ID and 
displays only the last output for each ID:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
text = open("logfile", "r").read()

regex = r'start (.+?)$(.+?)(?:(?=DEBUG[^\n]+?start)|\Z)+'
regex2 = r'Final output is (.+?)(?:(?=\nDEBUG)|\Z)'

for m in re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    print m.group(1)
    m2 = re.finditer(regex2, m.group(2), re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    print list(m2).pop().group(1).replace('\n', ' ')
```

input logfile:

```
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID1>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output
output output
output"
DEBUG: extra lines
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "this
is the last output
for <ID1>"
DEBUG: extra lines

DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID2>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output2
output+ output/
output2"
```

and output:

```
<ID1>
"this is the last output  for <ID1>"
<ID2>
"output2 output+ output/ output2"
```

I've divided the extraction of substrings into two steps:

1. to extract ID and remaining text (which may contain extra strings). This is processed with `regex`.
2. to extract "final output" substrings from the "remaining text" above. This is processed with `regex2`.

Then pick the last "final output" and display.

**EDIT**

The version below suppresses the message(s) which contains some keyword:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
text = open("logfile", "r").read()

exclude = 'xyz'     # keyword to suppress the output

regex = r'start (.+?)$(.+?)(?:(?=DEBUG[^\n]+?start)|\Z)+'
regex2 = r'Final output is (.+?)(?:(?=\nDEBUG)|\Z)'
#regex = r'start (.+?)$.*?Final output is (.+?)(?=\nDEBUG)'
#for m in re.finditer(regex, text, flags=(re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)):
for m in re.finditer(regex, text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    print m.group(1)
    m2 = re.finditer(regex2, m.group(2), re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    message = list(m2).pop().group(1).replace('\n', ' ')
    if message.count(exclude):
        print 'error:' + exclude
    else:
        print message
```

Sample logfile:

```
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID1>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output
output output
output"
DEBUG: extra lines
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "this
is the last output
for ID1"
DEBUG: extra lines

DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID2>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output2
output+ output/
output2"
DEBUG: extra lines

DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID3>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "this message
contains the word xyz"
DEBUG: extra lines
```

The output:

```
<ID1>
"this is the last output  for ID1"
<ID2>
"output2 output+ output/ output2"
<ID3>
error:xyz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is very accurate.

Comment: what can i do if there are multiple "final output" for a single <ID> and i want to fetch only the last one.

Comment: If the count of multiple "final output" is limited up to say, two or three, then the modification of regex will work. If arbitrary number of "final outputs" are possible, we may need to find another approach. Can you describe the example log file?

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your comment. It should work for any number of "final output". If my assumption and/or the expected output differs from yours, please let me know. BR.

Comment: Thanks you're awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Would it be possible to exclude printing the output if a certain word comes in it. For example - if 'xyz' comes in the output, I don't want to print the output instead print 'error:xyz'.

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer accordingly. As a next step, you may want to
make it work with multiple keywords and/or the keyword(s) can be supplied
in the command line option. I'll set it aside as your homework.

Answer (score 2):

Sample log file:

```
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start 12324
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output output output output"
DEBUG: extra lines
```

Please find the code. Also, I am assuming you have only one instance of each ID and output

```
import sys, re

stream=open("log","r")
lines=stream.readlines()


flag_ID = 0
flag_output = 0
flag_print = 1
for i in lines:
    ID = re.match("DEBUG: [\w :]* start (\d+)", i)
    output = re.match("DEBUG: [\w :]* Final output is \"([\w ]*)\"", i)
    if ID:
        flag_ID = 1
        value_ID = ID.group(1)
    if output:
        flag_output = 1 
        value_output = output.group(1)
    if flag_output == 1 and flag_ID == 1 and flag_print == 1:
        print "{0} {1}".format(value_ID, value_output)
        flag_print = 0
```

output

```
12324 output output output output
```

Please tick mark and accept if this solves your problem ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There is one problem though since output can be anything (letters,numbers,symbols) so that regex "\"([\w ]*)\"" is not working quite properly.  I'm not good with regex. Could you please help me with the regex that can fetch different characters till the first occurence of "DEBUG"

Comment: You cna refer to below link to chekc your string
https://regex101.com/r/jE4cE4/62

Comment: So for example you want to include symbol -. The regex will be "\"([\w -]*)\"". Note the regex was already having space" " after \w which represents space.

Comment: I don't know why but in python code, the regex is not printing after a newline. I've used \n also

Comment: sorry, i didn;t get by "the regex is not printing after a newline". If you can your whole code  so if issue is different , you can ask new question as well.

Comment: Please check this - DEBUG.*final output is (.*\n.*) 
In regex101 it is fetching newline as well but when i apply same in python it doesn't fetch newlne

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184982/discussion-between-fullmetal-and-rishi-bansal).

Answer (score 0):

With Perl, you can do it with one-liner, if the file could fit into memory..

```
/tmp> cat debug.log
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: start <ID1>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16920: Final output is "output
output output
output"
DEBUG: extra lines
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16921 extra text
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16921: start <ID2>
DEBUG: Fri Dec  7 06:49:14 2018:16921: Final output is "output output output output"
DEBUG: extra lines
/tmpl>
/tmp> perl -0777 -ne ' while(/^DEBUG(.+?)start (\S+).*?DEBUG.+?Final output is \"(.+?)\"/smg) { print "$2 $3\n" } ' debug.log
<ID1> output
output output
output
<ID2> output output output output
/tmp>
```